# Set Theory: Proof that there is no surjection from $A$ to its powerset $\mathcal{P}(A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is my proof sufficient to prove that there is no surjection from set $A$ to its powerset $\mathcal{P}(A)$ if A is infinite?

Pf. by Contradiction: Suppose there is surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Let $n$ be the number of elements in set $A$.

This implies that $n≥2^n$ because every element in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ must have a pointer to it from an element in $A$. This is a contradiction because there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the inequality $n≥2^n$ is satisfied. Q.E.D.

Comment: You didn't prove anything. Why does this imply what you say? It doesn't say this at all, actually. What if $A$ is infinite?

Comment: Just knowing that a proposition holds for *finite* cardinals tells you nothing about its behavior for *infinite* cardinals. For instance, there is no finite $n$ such that $n+1=n$, but $\kappa+1=\kappa$ is true for lots of infinite cardinals $\kappa$ (in fact, for all of them, if we assume the axiom of choice).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do we really need AC for that statement?

Comment: @Tobias: Well, countable choice is enough. $\kappa+1=\kappa$ if and only if $\aleph_0\leq\kappa$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. Still somewhat surprising to me that any amount of choice is needed (but my intuition for that is not very good anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work, because when $A$ is infinite, then $|A|$ is not a natural number. So you cant say $2^n \geq n$, because $n$ is not natural. It is exactly what you want to prove.

This has been proven by Cantor. I'm sure the argument can be find on the internet easily.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof does not take into account that $A$ can be infinite.

In other words, where you made the mistake was at the sentence:

> Let $n$ be the number of elements in $A$

Because here, you assumed that $n$ is an element of $\mathbb N$, and this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let me call $\phi$ the function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$; $i.e.$ $\phi:A\longrightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Let $B=\{x\in A\text{ }|\text{ } x\notin \phi(x) \}$; prove that there not exists any $y\in A$ such that $\phi(y)=B$.